# Can Windows system beeps be disabled on a per-application basis?

Tags: windows, windows-10, system-sounds

MATLAB on Windows has an annoying tendency to produce error beeps at the slightest thing, most notably upon reaching the start or end of the command history, but also for a host of other reasons. This cannot be disabled within MATLAB (despite over 7 years of people complaining about it). Basically the only proposed "solution" to this issue is to either mute all system sounds via the volume mixer, or disable the system beep sound system-wide. This is obviously ridiculous as as solution, as it also prevents system beeps from any other application, some of which may be important.

So the question is: is it possible, within Windows 10, to disable system beeps, or system sounds in general, from applications on a per-application basis? In other words, can I make MATLAB shut up without muting system beeps from all other applications at the same time?

Comment: More than likely it is hard coded into the software, only solution is to disable it system wide.

Comment: That was what I suspected (the hard coding). Are you suggesting that there is no way to mute system sounds from a single app;ication within Windows?

Comment: Not that I know of unless someone has a 3rd party program that can do it.